# How can I resize this photo for a 16" x 20" frame?

Tags: photoshop, aspect-ratio

So I have a photo of a friend that was merged not sure if that's the right word for it. I am doing a canvas for him 16x20. I have tried to print the pic, that will not be a canvas wrap. This file is huge and I have asked several of my close friends that are photographers to talk me through resizing it. They even tried for me and it's still cutting off about 3 inches.[image: Timmy tattooing Timmy]

I'm at a lose any suggestions? The shoes are very important to stay in frame

Answer (score 7):

Your image is more rectangular than your desired final product (16x20).  The version of the image you're showing here is 960x660, so the width of your image is 50% longer than the height.

If you want to print to 16x20, then the width (20") can only be 25% longer than the height (16")

If you can't chop off any of the left or right portions of the image, then you'll have to choose a custom size, like 14x20, that fits the proportions of your image.

Or you'd have to fill in the top and/or bottom (with black or using something like Photoshop's content-aware fill)

Comment: Thank you so much i have spent 4 days trying to figure it out. This is a starting point. I will try that.

Comment: One rectangle cannot be more "rectangular" than another rectangle!

Comment: Haha! Yeah I guess I meant less square.

Answer (score 1):

To match the aspect ratio of the image, you need to print at either 16x24, 12x18,  or any other 3:2 (1.5) aspect ratio. 16x20 is a 4:5 (1.25) aspect ratio.